# How to display more than 3 items in a BottomNavigationBar while coding in flutter

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

I tried adding 5 BottomNavigationBarItem but, the compiler throws an error if I try to add more than 3 items. It looks something like this:

```
 The following RangeError was thrown building BottomNavigationBar(dirty, state:
_BottomNavigationBarState#a56dd(tickers: tracking 3 tickers)):
 RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3
```

I need to display 5 items in the BottomNavigationBar. Help me out on this one.

[BottomNavigationBar missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791835/bottomnavigationbar-missing)

there is the link to the code and, currently there are just three items in there, I wanna add two more items without the compiler throwing error message

Comment: Does the number of children of the PageView match the number of bottom navigation items? Please show more code in the question.

Comment: code is same as the one in the link

Comment: Share your code. It seems you are using something at index = 3, but you have only 3 items (index range = 0..2). So index = 3 is invalid

Comment: I added the link, please do take a look at the code.

Answer (score 57):

Just writing it for the future query regarding on this issue.

Just add a extra parameter in your BottomNavigationBar Constructor -

`type : BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`

[Check also the Flutter Official Ref.](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/BottomNavigationBar.html)

Optional : Restart your app from start for fixing rendering issue.

Comment: The provided link is broken, here is the current one - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Answer (score 26):

It's because the default NavigatioBar doesn't support more than 3 items, **Use this parameter inside your BottomNavigationBar widget:**
`type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`

**OR Copy and Paste this code below**

```
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
     type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, ///This allow more than 3 items
     backgroundColor: Theme.Colors.primaryDarkColor,
    currentIndex: 1,
     items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,), title: Text("GLO", 
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), title: 
    Text("MTN"),),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), title: 
    Text("Airtel"),),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), title: 
    Text("9mobile"),),
     ],
  ),
```